# Access outer function param without passing in inner function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function which does an async call & calls an anonymous function on success.The `data` param of anonymous function is used to collect the response from the server but it is not available inside the inner function unless passed as a param.

```
callService('POST', getDataInfo, detailData, function (data) {
            formDisplayGrid('.accruedGrid', '.accruedTable', 'Total Accrued');//doesn't work.
            formDisplayGrid(data,'.accruedGrid', '.accruedTable', 'Total Accrued'); //works
           });
```

`callService` is just a function which uses jQuery ajax to place a call.

```
function callService(method, url, data, success) {
        var ajaxObject = {
            url: url,
            method: method,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: success
        }
        if (method == 'POST') {
            ajaxObject['data'] = data;
        }
        jQuery.ajax(ajaxObject);
    }
```

`formDisplayGrid` function just iterates over dataset to form HTML table.

```
function formDisplayGrid(data, modalSelector, mainGridSelector, totalLabel) {    
    jQuery(modalSelector).modal();
    if (typeof data != 'undefined' && data.Code === 200) {
        var mainGrid = jQuery(mainGridSelector);
        var tbody = '';

        jQuery.each(data['Data']['category'], function (k, v) {
            //some code here.
            jQuery.each(v['subcat'], function (k, v) {
                //some code here.
            });    
        });    
                //some code here.
        mainGrid.find('tbody').html(tbody).fadeIn(1200);
    }
}
```

Is that this is happening because the anonymous function is being executed in
the `jQuery.ajax` function and it should have been available if the anonymous function was directly executed inside the `callService` function?

Comment: please share the formDisplayGrid function code also

Comment: @orangespark updated

Comment: i think the approach of passing data as an argument is better as it will modularise your functions and decouple them. Writing pure functions is a better way to go.

Comment: @orangespark yes obviously but I m just trying to clarify the concept.

Comment: the concept is basically simple, your formDisplayGrid function is an external function to callback function so it shouldn't have access to the private variables within that callback function.But if u want the first approach to work u will have to define the function inside the callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is basically simple, your formDisplayGrid() function is an external function to callback function so it shouldn't have access to the private variables within that callback function.But if you want the first approach to work u will have to define the function inside the callback function.

Comment: Function body needs to be nested inside and not written elsewhere.

Comment: I have mentioned that in the last line :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `formDisplayGrid` function won't be able to access any variables from where it was called unless those variables are global or they are in a closure.

EDIT: your function has to get its `data` argument from somewhere - otherwise how is it going to know what data is?. There is a good reason that only the second one works.

EDIT2: here is a solution with a closure:

```
callService('POST', getDataInfo, detailData, function (data) {
    function formDisplayGrid(modalSelector, mainGridSelector, totalLabel) {
        // you no longer need the data variable    
        jQuery(modalSelector).modal();
        if (typeof data != 'undefined' && data.Code === 200) {
            var mainGrid = jQuery(mainGridSelector);
            var tbody = '';

            jQuery.each(data['Data']['category'], function (k, v) {
            //some code here.
                jQuery.each(v['subcat'], function (k, v) {
                //some code here.
                });    
            });    
                //some code here.
            mainGrid.find('tbody').html(tbody).fadeIn(1200);
        }
    }
    formDisplayGrid('.accruedGrid', '.accruedTable', 'Total Accrued');//should work.
});
```

Comment: I was expecting that the anonymous function would form a closure and its param `data` would automatically be available inside the `formDisplayGrid` function as per laws of closure.

Comment: For that the formDisplayGrid function definition should be inside the callback function

Comment: @orangespark That means inner function would get the access to `data` only if its body is nested and not when it is called by name?

Comment: exactly :) otherwise every funciton called can access its environment variables.

Comment: @orangespark ok could you please post that as an answer so that I can mark it?

Comment: @techie_28   I have posted the answer